# Navigation back between two fragment xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

**MainActivity**

```cs
ActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator (Resource.Drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (true);
drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout> (Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView> (Resource.Id.nav_view);
```

**Event click on navigatonView**

```cs
CreateFragments();
LoadInditialFragment ();        

navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected;
```

- Onefragment
- Twofragment

Navigation back from second Fragment to first fragment(navigation back on toolbar).??? MainActivity I have a button menu on toolbar.
I want to replace menu icon into back icon  when It is standing at second fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Download back arrow and save as navBack.png

Then in `SwitchFragment` method where we navigate between fragments

```
switch (FragmentId) {
 case Resource.Id.nav_home:
 ActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator (Resource.Drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
 transaction.Show (homeFragment);
  transaction.Commit (); 
  break; 
   case Resource.Id.nav_genre:
  ActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator (Resource.Drawable.navBack);
   transaction.Show (genresFragment);
    transaction.Commit ();
     break;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your MainActivity do this in `OnCreate`:

```
SupportFragmentManager.BackStackChanged += HandleBackstackChanged;
```

Implement the `HandleBackstackChanged` method like this

```
private void HandleBackstackChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (SupportFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount > 0);
}
```

What this will do is toggle between the `Menu` button and the `Back` button based on the BackStack count of the FragmentManager.

**NOTE:**
I am assuming you are using the Support library for backwards compatibility of `Fragments`. If you aren't using the support library, just use `FragmentManger` instead of `SupportFragmentManager`.